# Default Data + Tensor location with Tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

By default, are Tensors as well Keras Datasets (once loaded) placed on the GPU when using Tensorflow 2? Or CPU?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), it basically uses to RAM load data and based on the tf.data pipeline, it uses both CPU and GPU.
Below image will give you clear idea about the same.
[image]